# What's the easiest way to check for unused references?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

My Solution in Visual Studio 2017 has many projects. A project references many other projects; I am suspicious of unnecessary references to projects not used or no longer used. What's the easiest way to check for unnecessary references?

Comment: Resharper: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ is an amazing tool to manage these kind if things. It is not free but a trial for 30 days you can quiqly better your solution

Comment: In reference to resharper, if you've got a student email address (active or alumni, forwarding all mail) you can get a free Jetbrains Student License :)

Comment: It is only for one year student license + 30 days trail.

Comment: There's also free licenses for open-source projects

Comment: Duplicate? Yes, but the previous question has no answer.

Comment: But maybe some day it has one. And then people finding your question would see that answer. Because they are pointed that way. There is not much use in having more than one open question for the same problem.

Comment: Foolishness. That dead 2009 question has "There is no answer" marked as an answer. Closing this question just reinforces that false answer. You are just perpetuating the misconception by ardently applying blind guidelines inappropriately. Just another demonstration how StackOverflow is so broken.